# Не могу добавить bootstrap-иконку

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Хочу сделать таблицу с различными иконками в каждой странице. Не получается подсунуть эти эконки, они вообще не отображаются. Вот разметка:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h3>Список задач</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Название задачи</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Вынести мусор
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Ссылка на [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hXhWYNo226AXWx9wDucJ?p=preview) прилагается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В бустрапе 4 нет иконок.
Используйте 3.